# How to do Masquerading with NFTables

Tags: iptables, nftables

How would I implement a masquerading rule like this iptables one in NFTables:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.5.6.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I've looked for it, but couldn't find out how to set the output interface

Comment: Did you not use this when migrating from iptables to nftables? {iptables-restore-translate -f save.txt > ruleset.nft nft -f ruleset.nft}

Answer (score 10):

You can write the rule this way:

```
nft add rule nat postrouting ip saddr 10.5.6.0/24 oif eth0 masquerade
```

Take a look on [nftables nat wiki](http://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Performing_Network_Address_Translation_(NAT)) for more informations.

Answer (score 10):

as an aside, if you were masquerading under a dynamic address, you could simply

`add rule nat postrouting oif ppp0 masquerade`

---

## `oif` / `oifname`

*Userspace converts `oif` to integer at runtime*

You should use probably use `oifname` (*slower* string matching) rather than `oif` if the interface might disappear and then re-appear (like ppp0 and others may, upon disconnect, etc.) unless you'll make other arrangements to masquerade upon the interface coming up each time.

> **`oif`** → if the interface is removed and created again, the match will not occur as the index of added interfaces in kernel is monotonically increasing. 
> —*via* [nftables-quick-howto](https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/nftables-quick-howto/)

Answer (score 0):

I have the following "nat" table in my `/etc/nftables.conf` file, along with my other firewall rules which are in a separate "filter" table :

```
table ip nat {
    chain prerouting {
        type nat hook prerouting priority filter; policy accept;
    }
                 
    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        oifname { "eno2" } masquerade   # "eno2" is our external interface
    }
}

table ip filter {
    # etc.
```